# What does this phrase mean here: "it may be considered to be agreed"? Is the thing agreed upon, or not?

Tags: meaning

In the case of individual self-defence, the exercise of this right is subject to
the State concerned having been the victim of an armed attack. Reliance on collective
self-defence of course does not remove the need for this. There appears now to
be general agreement on the nature of the acts which can be treated as constituting
armed attacks. In particular, **it may be considered to be agreed** that an armed attack
must be understood as including not merely action by regular armed forces across
an international border, but also ‘the sending by or on behalf of a State of armed
bands, groups, irregulars or mercenaries, which carry out acts of armed force against
another State of such gravity as to amount to’ (inter alia) an actual armed attack
conducted by regular forces, ‘or its substantial involvement therein’.

Answer (score 2):

***it may be considered to be X***
 is equivalent to
 *[for the purposes of the current discussion] **let us agree** that it is **in fact** X*

So in the cited context, all the writer is really saying is ***let us agree to agree*** [that an armed attack must be blah blah]. Which is just a long-winded way of saying ***An armed attack is blah blah.*** Don't copy this style.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither agreed upon nor denied. It is intentionally left ambiguous so as to decide on a case-by-case basis.

It is only agreed to *consider* acts of armed bands, groups, irregulars or mercenaries acting on behalf of a State as an actual armed attack conducted by regular forces. However it may not directly be agreed that *all* acts of such entities might constitute an actual armed attack from the State. Because the extent and extremity of an attack varies remarkably.

"It may be considered to be agreed" is the way of saying we will consider such external acts as an actual attack by a State, but we need to investigate it further before we decide.

Comment: I see nothing in the cited usage to imply that "further investigation might be required" in any specific circumstances.

Comment: It is implied from the context of the citation.

Comment: Like I said, I see nothing implying that. What I *do* see is *X **must** be understood as Y*, which unequivocally states that the category X must be broadened to include Y. This despite the fact that *in other circumstances,* or from a different perspective, Y might not be included within the category X.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, X must be broadened to include Y under certain circumstances. Could you please say how to arrive at these certain circumstances? How do they decide a circumstance has enough girth to be classified as a Y?

Comment: I don't see how any of that makes any difference. The relevant "certain circumstances" are simply *the context of the current "conversation"*. Within which context it's quite true that an expression like ***X may be considered to be Y*** does indeed imply that *strictly speaking*, X is ***not*** Y - but for the purposes of the discussion, it's easier if we assume / agree that X ***is*** Y. Which has no implications whatsoever regarding whether *in the real world, outside the context of this discussion*, there might be some "marginal" cases to be decided upon.